# How to control responsive flow

Tags: css, html, layout, responsive-design

I'm making a responsive site and have a callout style box floated to the top right of the main text. When the window is narrower I want the callout to appear full width below the main text, not above.

Here's a code sample: http://codepen.io/creativetags/full/ydozx

Comment: Move the side-col div to be below the main-col div in the markup. You'll have to adjust the CSS to make it position in the top left in the normal view though.

Comment: Absolute positioning covers main column in normal view: http://codepen.io/creativetags/pen/Fqitw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).
First, move main-col above side-col. Then this in your .css file should give you control.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
.main-col {
float: none;
width: 100%;
}

.side-col {
float: none;
width: 100%;
background-color: silver;
}
```

This will apply the css for screen sizes that are 360px or below.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
.main-col {
float: left;
width: 83%;
}

.side-col {
float: left;
width: 17%;
background-color: silver;
}
```

This will apply for screen sizes above 360px.

If having the text wrap is a must though, then try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KlmIF

Comment: That might work if the sidebar was a full height column but it's a callout style box. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hmm unless I'm missing something I don't see how that'd make a difference? Based on the code here: http://codepen.io/creativetags/full/ydozx my answer should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: Minimize your browser screen and see it move to the bottom http://codepen.io/creativetags/full/Fqitw let me know if I'm missing something though.

Comment: Here's my version of your code: http://codepen.io/creativetags/pen/DBIFi
The side-col is no longer wrapped by the main-col like the original was in the wide view.

Comment: I'm not a great fan of the technique but if having them wrap is more important then.. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KlmIF

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing that. It's not clean but it works, thanks.